# Why does this Perl program not work as advertised

Tags: perl

I have to include a command line switch (-r) to reverse sort a list of strings inputted through the @ARGV array on the command line. I'm trying to find a good place to read about command line switches.  I can't find any good sources online that explain these topics clearly.

**Question 1:** does anyone know any good online sources that clearly explain this topic?

I found this example online, but I can't get it to work.  It will run at the command line, and  output 'hello, world'
but if I type `$perl -g filename.pl` it will output: *Unrecognized switch: -g  (-h will show valid options).*

**Question 2**  why isn't this working?  shouldn't it say 'goodbye world' with -g?

```
  #! /usr/local/bin/perl -s
  use strict;
  my( $switch, $thing );
  $switch = shift;
  if( $switch and $switch eq "-g" ) {
      $thing = shift || 'world';
  } else {
      $thing = $switch || shift || 'world';
      $switch = undef if $switch;
  }
  print $switch ? 'Goodbye' : 'Hello', ", $thing\n";
```

Comment: This code is an example of command line switches that came from perlmonks.org:  http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=88222

Comment: Switch should go not to the interpreter, but to the script: 'perl filename.pl -g'

Comment: I typed it on the command line as $perl filename.pl -g, and this time I get 'hello, world' not 'goodbye, world' as I thought it should be.  no 'unrecognized switch:g though!

Comment: Your input "perl -g filename.pl " is wrong. "perl filename.pl -g" will work.

Comment: @Fumu7: did you try it? it doesn't.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Good job using strict; you should also `use warnings;`.

Perl's syntax is:

```
   perl [ -sTtuUWX ]      [ -hv ] [ -V[:configvar] ]
        [ -cw ] [ -d[t][:debugger] ] [ -D[number/list] ]
        [ -pna ] [ -Fpattern ] [ -l[octal] ] [ -0[octal/hexadecimal] ]
        [ -Idir ] [ -m[-]module ] [ -M[-]'module...' ] [ -f ]
        [ -C [number/list] ]      [ -S ]      [ -x[dir] ]
        [ -i[extension] ]
        [ [-e|-E] 'command' ] [ -- ] [ programfile ] [ argument ]
```

Anything before the program file (or the optional --) is a command line switch that tells the perl interpreter to do something special; switches that are intended for your *perl program* need to come after the program filename, so: `perl filename.pl -g`, not `perl -g filename.pl`.

On your shebang line, you have `-s`; don't use this switch.  It is one of those features that haven't stood the test of time and doesn't play well with modern perl.  In this case, it is hiding the -g argument from you before your code even starts; remove it and you should see the results you expect.

And while there's *never* any good reason to use `-s`, you shouldn't hand-parse parameters either: use [Getopt::Long](http://p3rl.org/Getopt::Long).